# How to use field calculator to return the percentage of each record within a group (defined by a different field)? (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro

Within ArcGIS Pro, I am trying to summarize records in a shapefile by calculating a new attribute field that shows the percentage of a given record within each group, defined by another field in the attribute table.

Here is a dummy attribute data example of what I am trying to do. I am looking to use field calculator to calculate a new field `GROUP_PCT`:

```
ID, GROUP, VALUE, GROUP_PCT

1, A, 3, 75

2, A, 1, 25

3, B, 7, 43.75

4, B, 9, 56.25
```

So for record ID 3 (in group B):

```
GROUP_PCT = 7/(7+9)*100 = 43.75%
```

....record ID 3 makes up 43.75% of the sum of values in GROUP B.

Is there a smart simple way to do automate this with Python code block in field calculator (or otherwise)?

Comment: Field Calculator can only use the current record for each calculation.   You may want to try using Summary Statistics to produce a total (sum) for each group.  Then you should be able to join your data to the resulting statistics table (join on group field) and use Field Calculator on the joined table.

Comment: As @SonofaBeach indicates using summary statistics with a case field of GROUP and summary field of VALUE with a statistic type of SUM will give you the rows you need, you can leverage the in_memory workspace as part of a field calculator expression but it gets quite messy, this would work much better in a short python script. Do you have any python experience or interest?

Comment: A little! I took a course in graduate school a few years ago and use SQL. I imagine this could be created with conditional statements? Do you have an example?